# Returning elements from array

Tags: java

I'm trying to return an array. Consider the following code.

```
public Quiz[] getMark(){
}
```

This is what i have as the return method. I want to return all the elements in the array under this method. I have to use `return` and the return type has to be `Quiz[]`

How would i start off?

Comment: Start off with [the Java tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html) so you have the basics.

Comment: You posted code is just a definition of a method. After the access modifier 'public' you defined a return value from type of Quiz array. What we are missing is the source object. It does exsisting many ways to transfer elments to your value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you looking for this

```
public Quiz[] getMark(){

Quiz [] quizArr = new Quiz[5]; quizArr[0]= new Quiz(); ... .. ..

return quizArr; }
```

Comment: This gave me clues to fix it. Cheers

Comment: @ART: all other answers are identical to this one.

Answer (score 1):

May be this:

```
public Quiz[] getMark(){
  Quiz[] quizs;
  //--do some processing.
  //-- fill data in array
  return quizs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand what is the problem , arrays in java are objects you just return it

a possible implementation

```
public Quiz[] getMark(){
    //init the quiz array
    Quiz[] array = new Quiz[5];
    // init each element in the quiz array
    for (int i=0;i<5;++i){
        array[i] = new Quiz();  // could use different constructor
    }
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

public Quiz[] getMark(){

```
return quizList.toArray(new Quiz[quizList.size()]());
```

}